# Outlook power user rules without elevated permissions

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-client, email-filter

I recently made the switch to the new Office 365 Outlook app redesign, and I'm encountering difficulties in setting up advanced email rules that take into account the context of email threads, such as the stage of a new issue, for the purpose of labeling emails. To provide some examples:

> If the email body contains the phrase 'key*word' and sent from 'address1' categorize it as 'issue/fresh'
>
> If the email body contains 'keyword' and sent from '@companymail.com' and not from 'address1' categorize it as 'issue/stale.'
>
> If the email body contains the word 'final' and sent from '*@companymail.com' but not from 'address1' categorize it as 'issue/closed.'

I'm essentially looking for a solution that allows me to create simple rules similar to what [Protonmail's Sieve filters](https://proton.me/support/sieve-advanced-custom-filters) offer. My current approach involves managing this by setting up multiple, mutually exclusive rules, which is far from ideal and quite cumbersome.

I've been advised to explore Power Automate for Outlook as it seems to be more effective than using "outlook rules". However, I'm unsure of how to proceed and I want to accomplish this without needing elevated permissions.

Is it possible to perform Outlook email filtering using Power Automate or any other tool without requiring elevated permissions, or are "Outlook rules" the only available option?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to perform Outlook email filtering using Power Automate or any other tool without requiring elevated permissions, or are "Outlook rules" the only available option?

Haven't heard of any other tool which can be used for this requirement. And based on my research, seems like Power Automate cannot fulfil your needs either because it doesn't have the condition to filter based on message body. Available conditions are as follows:
[image]
See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/email-triggers?tabs=classic-designer).

Taken in the round, settings up Outlook rules might be the only option at present.

Comment: Power Automate seems actually more limited than Outlook rules in filtering incoming emails.

Comment: They work differently and have differences in terms of features and limitations. Here's a post about this topic for reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftFlow/comments/xutxp6/power_automate_or_outlook_rules/